# Grails date validation in view

Tags: javascript, regex, grails

I have a problem with date validation in .gsp files. When user enters date in a wrong format, I want that a javascript alert appears with information what went wrong.

Well, the catch is that I use templates and I'm not allowed to use something else. The form is in _form.gsp and the submit button is in create.gsp.

create.gsp

```
<g:form action="save">

    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
  <g:submitButton name="create" onsubmit="validate()"
value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />

            <g:render template="form" />

        </g:form>
```

_form.gsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validate()
 {
  var dValidate=document.getElementById('myDateFormat');
   if(dValidate!="")
   {
     var arDValidate=dValidate.split(".");
    if(arDValidate.length==3)
    {
       if(arDValidate[0].length!=2 || (arDValidate[0]>32))
       {
         alert("Wrong Date format");
         return false;
      }
      else if(arDValidate[1].length!=2 || (arDValidate[1]>13))
      {
         alert("Wrong Month format");
         return false;
       }
       else if(arDValidate[2].length!=4 || (arDValidate[2]<1900))
       {
         alert("Wrong Year format");
          return false;
      }
      else
       {
         var dateDate=new Date(arDValidate[2],arDValidate[1]-1,arDValidate[0]);
         if((arDValidate[0]!=dateDate.getDate()))
          {
           alert("Wrong Date Enter e.g date month year is not correct 31 feb 2009");
           return false;
            }
          }
         }
    else
    {
    alert("Wrong Format");
    return false;
     }
 }
  else
  {
   alert("Date is blank");
   return false;
  }
}

</script>
```

............

```
<div class="fieldcontain required">
 <div>  
<g:textField name="validFrom" id="myDateFormat" required=""          value="${
 g.formatDate(date:newsInstance?.validFrom, 
format:   g.message(code:'app.date.format', default:'dd.MM.yyyy.'))}"/></div>
          </div>

<div class="fieldcontain required">
 <div>  
<g:textField name="validTo" id="myDateFormat" required=""          value="${
 g.formatDate(date:newsInstance?.validTo, 
format:   g.message(code:'app.date.format', default:'dd.MM.yyyy.'))}"/></div>
          </div>
```

I call validate() function in create.gsp and this is probably wrong but as I said, there are two files and I don't know how to connect them.

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont understand why you cant change things in the template. because you can use <g:datePicker> so you wont have to worry about the way the user would enter data??? and  when you are talking about two files you cant connect, are you referring to 'create.gsp' and '_form.gsp' because if so you can just treat them as one, or you can replace everything in _form.gsp instead of <g:render template="form" /> ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Templates

> I call validate() function in create.gsp and this is probably wrong
>   but as I said, there are two files and I don't know how to connect
>   them.

You can use templates to avoid duplication of code, because you can link them in any other GSP. Basically what Grails does is to merge your files and produce the final html that will be sent to your browser. So you can have something like:

**_form.gsp**

```
...
<g:textField name="myfield" />
...
```

And you can guarantee that this input is visible in the create and update actions:

```
<g:render template="_form" />
```

If you check the source code in your browser, you will see that the html have the content of both: _form and create.

---

### JavaScript Validations

About your date validation, is more likely that this will be used in a lot of views, so even your template is not the correct place to put it.

Grails have a lot of convention for separation of source files. For JavaScript you can use `web-app/js`. According to this convention, a solution could be:

**web-app/js/validations.js**

```
function checkDate(field) {
  //your validation goes here
}
```

You can link it in your GSP, or use the Grails layout to make it available for all views:

**grails-app/views/layout/main.gsp**

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type='text/javascript' src='${g.resource(dir: "js", file: "validations.js")}'></script>
  ...
</head>
```

And finally you must define **when** this validation will be triggered (before submit, after focus leaves the field...).

**_form.gsp**

```
<g:textField name="validFrom" ... onblur="checkDate(this);" />
```

---

### JQuery Validations

JavaScript validation can be a repetitive task. You can check the [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://limcheekin.github.io/jquery-validation-ui/docs/guide/overview.html) that tries to make it easier, by adding client side validations like Grails does to the server side.

### Further Reading

The Grails documentation is a good place to understand more about how things are tight together. I suggest you to start [in the Web Layer](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html) section and probably things will make more sense.